# python3 setup-gn.py won't compile while installing ios version of chromium source code

Tags: python, macos, shell, installation, chromium

So i'm installing Chromium source code and trying to get ios code but keep getting error. Here's a documentation i'm following: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/ios/build_instructions.md

When i'm trying to run python3 setup-gn.py i keep getting an error:

```
markmarus@MacBook-Pro-Mark tools % python3 setup-gn.py
ERROR at //build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn:1343:22: Script returned non-zero exit code.
    clang_revision = exec_script("//tools/clang/scripts/update.py",
                     ^----------
Current dir: /Users/markmarus/src/out/_tempzfw_t_3r/
Command: python3 /Users/markmarus/src/tools/clang/scripts/update.py --print-revision --verify-version=16.0.0
Returned 1 and printed out:

The expected clang version is llvmorg-16-init-8697-g60809cd2-1 but the actual version is 
Did you run "gclient sync"?

See //build/config/BUILDCONFIG.gn:334:3: which caused the file to be included.
  "//build/config/compiler:afdo_optimize_size",
  ^-------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/markmarus/src/ios/build/tools/setup-gn.py", line 340, in <module>
    sys.exit(Main(sys.argv[1:]))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/markmarus/src/ios/build/tools/setup-gn.py", line 336, in Main
    GenerateXcodeProject(gn_path, args.root, args.proj_name, out_dir, settings)
  File "/Users/markmarus/src/ios/build/tools/setup-gn.py", line 220, in GenerateXcodeProject
    generator.Generate(gn_path, proj_name, root_dir, temp_path)
  File "/Users/markmarus/src/ios/build/tools/setup-gn.py", line 114, in Generate
    subprocess.check_call(self.GetGnCommand(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/gn', '--root=/Users/markmarus/src', '-q', '--ide=xcode', '--ninja-executable=autoninja', '--xcode-build-system=new', '--xcode-project=all', '--xcode-additional-files-patterns=*.md', '--xcode-additional-files-roots=//ios;//ios_internal;//docs', '--xcode-configs=Debug;Release;Profile;Official', '--xcode-config-build-dir=//out/${CONFIGURATION}${EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME}', '--filters=//base:base_unittests;//components:components_unittests;//crypto:crypto_unittests;//google_apis:google_apis_unittests;//ios/*;//ios_internal/*;//net:net_unittests;//services:services_unittests;//skia:skia_unittests;//sql:sql_unittests;//ui/base:ui_base_unittests;//ui/gfx:gfx_unittests;//url:url_unittests;//third_party/crashpad/*', 'gen', '//out/_tempzfw_t_3r']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
markmarus@MacBook-Pro-Mark tools % build.py
```

I simply can't run the command

Comment: Do you have the XCode command line tools installed and on your PATH?

Comment: I do have it installed but my path goes to depot_tools

Comment: Did you run `gclient sync`? It will pull all the third-party dependencies needed for Chromium to compile